# Convert 31/07/2010 to Date format like 2014-07-31

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-format

Is there a function wich can convert a date in format like :

31/07/2014 to a format date like 2014-07-31

I want to do this because in my sql query when i put the date in the format with " / " it doesn't understand te format :/

I have this message : `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '30/07/2014' for column 'date_recu' at row 1' in C:\wamp\www\ajouter_lot2.php on line 76`

in my sql table, the type of the date is in datetime.

**Query**

```
$bdd->query('insert into LOT (id_lot,num_ref,date_recu,qty,remarque1,remarque2)
                    VALUES 
                    (NULL, "'.$Num_Ref.'","'.$Date_Recu.'",\''.$Qty.'\',"'.$Rem1_Lot.'","'.$Rem2_Lot.'")');
```

Where $Date_Recu = "31/07/2014"

**Solution with strtotime()**

```
$Date_Recu = strtotime($Date_Recu);               /* shows 31/07/2014 */
$Date_Recu =  date('Y-m-d', $Date_Recu);
echo 'Date Recu : '.$Date_Recu;                   /* shows 2014-07-31 */
```

Comment: you should use strtotime() function and save in timestamp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php

Comment: How about specifying your query?

Comment: I edited with my query, the problem is really the format of the $Date_Recu, I tried with substring function but it takes too many lines just to format :/

Comment: Which database you are using??

Comment: MySql Workbench. "strtotime()" seems to work fine ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the date into the format MySQL can understand.

```
$Date_Recu = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $Date_Recu)->format('Y-m-d');
```

You should not use strtotime on dates in the d/m/Y format because it has no way of knowing if the format is actually d/m/Y or m/d/Y.  Use a function like date_create_from_format where can you specify the format as well.

Comment: I finally decided to choose your option ^^ Mine isn't reliable at 100% :p

Answer (score 1):

You can try this either:-

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Which will resulted as `2014-07-31.`